# How can I run Java code contained in a .txt file?

Tags: java, terminal

How do you run code in a .txt file?

I know you're supposed to use a terminal, but it keeps giving this message:

> javac: file not found: hii.java 
> Usage: javac <options> <source files>  
> use -help for a list of possible options

I saved my .txt file on the desktop.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  what is the exact command you're using?  It's not clear what you're doing to see that error.

Comment: hello I am typing: javac hii.java into terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a file with extension .java, for example *Hi.java*.
2. Inside your *Hi.java* file, create something like:

   ```
   public class Hi {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("Hi");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Open a terminal in the directory where your *Hi.java* file is located (in your example in the desktop).
4. In the terminal, run the command:

   ```
   javac Hi.java
   ```

The file *Hi.class* should be created in your current directory (Desktop).

5. In the terminal, run the command:

   ```
   java Hi
   ```

Note that:

In Java files should terminate with *.java*, and it is best practice that a file name should start with a capital letter. You cannot use a file with extension *.txt* or any other extension. If you want to run a Java class then a .java filename extension is required and is not optional.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this, I cannot even think of where to start.

Just try something like [JCreator Lite Edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCreator) (LE), and try to work in it for a bit.

While it is loading, I suggest reading something like [this](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-command-prompt-introduction/). You have to be in the same working directory as your file when you run that command.